# Captcha cannot be submitted

Tags: support, captcha

I got captcha verification about picking up certain images from list. I did so and got some text to copy and paste in a new box. I pasted it, but there is no button to submit the same. I looked everywhere, but it was not there. When I press enter, it just adds new line but nothing else happens.

Wondering if any of my extensions is blocking it, see the screenshot, I have disconnect and privacybadger installed, but it dont have anything blocked from google other than google analytics.

[image: Captcha]

Comment: Whatever, robot.